# I'm new in React.js and have this error: "Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client

I'm doing a course of React Js, in the terminal not have errors but i have a error in the console of the navigator.

This is the error:

**Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `ToggleLikeMutation`.
at ToggleLikeMutation (webpack://curso-platzi-react-avanzado/./src/container/ToggleLikeMutation.js?:16:23)
at article
at styled.article (webpack://curso-platzi-react-avanzado/./node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js?:29:19307)
at PhotoCard (webpack://curso-platzi-react-avanzado/./src/components/PhotoCard/index.js?:31:17)
at ul
at ListOfPhotoCards (webpack://curso-platzi-react-avanzado/./src/components/ListOfPhotoCards/index.js?:22:25)
at div
at App
at ApolloProvider (webpack://curso-platzi-react-avanzado/./node_modules/@apollo/client/react/context/ApolloProvider.js?:12:21)**

Here's my documents:

*FavButton.js*

```
import React from 'react'
import { MdFavoriteBorder, MdFavorite } from 'react-icons/md'
import { Button } from './styles'

export const FavButton = ({ liked, likes, onClick }) => {
  const Icon = liked ? MdFavorite : MdFavoriteBorder

  return (
    <Button onClick={onClick}>
      <Icon size='32px' /> {likes} likes!
    </Button>
  )
}
```

*ToggleLikeMutation.js*

```
import React from 'react'
import { Mutation, gql } from '@apollo/client'

const LIKE_PHOTO = gql`
mutation likeAnonymusPhoto($input: LikePhoto!) {
    likeAnonymousPhoto(input: $input) {
      id,
      liked,
      likes
    }
}
`

export const ToggleLikeMutation = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Mutation mutation={LIKE_PHOTO}>
      {children}
    </Mutation>
  )
}
```

*PhotoCard.js*

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Article, ImgWrapper, Img } from './styles'
import { useLocalStorage } from '../../hooks/useLocalStorage'
import { useNearScreen } from '../../hooks/useNearScreen'
import { FavButton } from '../FavButton/index.js'
import { ToggleLikeMutation } from '../../container/ToggleLikeMutation'

const DEFAULT_IMAGE = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60'

export const PhotoCard = ({
  id, likes = 0,
  src = DEFAULT_IMAGE
}) => {
  const [show, element] = useNearScreen()
  const key = `like-${id}`
  const [liked, setLiked] = useLocalStorage(key, false)

  return (
    <Article ref={element}>
      {
        show &&
          <>
            <a href={`/?detail=${id}`}>
              <ImgWrapper>
                <Img src={src} />
              </ImgWrapper>
            </a>

            <ToggleLikeMutation>
              {
                (toggleLike) => {
                  const handleFavClick = () => {
                    !liked && toggleLike({
                      variables: {
                        input: { id }
                      }
                    })

                    setLiked(!liked)
                  }

                  return (
                    <FavButton
                      liked={liked} likes={likes} onClick={handleFavClick}
                    />
                  )
                }
              }
            </ToggleLikeMutation>
          </>
      }
    </Article>
  )
}
```

*App.js*

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { ListOfCategories } from './components/ListOfCategories'
import { GlobalStyle } from './styles/GlobalStyles'
import { ListOfPhotoCards } from './components/ListOfPhotoCards'
import { Logo } from './components/Logo'
import { PhotoCardWithQuery } from './container/PhotoCardWithQuery'

export const App = () => {
  const urlParams = new window.URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
  const detailId = urlParams.get('detail')

  return (
    <div>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Logo />
      {
        detailId
          ? <PhotoCardWithQuery id={detailId} />
          : <>
            <ListOfCategories />
            <ListOfPhotoCards categoryId={1} />
          </>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

*index.js*

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-boost'
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client'
import { App } from './App'

const cache = new InMemoryCache()

const link = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'https://petgram-jv-2011.vercel.app/graphql'
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: After `import { Mutation, gql } from '@apollo/client'` try `console.log(Mutation)` and check the result. The components are deprecated; apollo uses the `useMutation` hook now. Maybe your version of the library has already removed the component.

Comment: According to the [Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/components/#installation) (which, as mentioned by @ChrisG, say that the components are deprecated) you should be importing the components from `@apollo/client/react/components`.

Comment: Thanks, `useMutation`  resolve my error but i have new error with the use of this.

My new error is:
**Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.**